# Fully decentralized network for mobile robots using ROS2

Tags: ros2, mobile-robot, network

We want to demonstrate a decentralized algorithm for a team of mobile robots (~ 10 robots). We have WiFi adapters on each robot. It is not clear how we can do peer-to-peer communication between robots. We do not want to have a centralized router for communication. How can such a system be implemented? I couldn't find anything in the ROS2 documentation. The [fast-DDS discovery server](https://fast-dds.docs.eprosima.com/en/latest/fastdds/ros2/discovery_server/ros2_discovery_server.html) was the best I could find. But it seems we would need a centralized server for this as well. Maybe each robot acts as a discovery server.

Notes:

1. Mobile robots are moving in the environment. So, there will be a loss of communication and a change in the network topology.
2. One possible solution we were considering was that each robot alternately broadcasts its message and receives a broadcast message. I am not sure if this is the best solution and how to implement it in ROS2.

P.S.: I understand that this might be a vague question at the moment. I will improve it as I get more concrete information.

Answer (score 3):

ROS2 is inherently decentralized as it uses DDS. So as long as the controller hostnames are known to eachother (via a private network/VPN or some other goofy networking if not on the same router), these controllers are all seen as being in the same ROS2 ecosystem when configured correctly and can publish/subscribe to topics.

I did this with ROS1 using husarnet VPN because it's lightweight and pretty much plug and play (and it has good documentation with ROS). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. Husarnet seems to have a solution for ROS2 as well. The robots do not have a centralized router. So, I guess we will need some "other goofy networking". But that's what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: Do all robots have access to the internet? If so, husarnet will be your solution. Little additional networking required. It creates a virtual network that would pretty much act as if the controller's were on the same central router (hostnames and IP's will be discoverable to eachother)

Comment: We can have internet access during setup. However, in practice, we do not want to have internet access, as it would no longer be a decentralized system.

Comment: Interesting what is going to be the communication medium then?

Comment: Each robot has a WiFi adapter. They should be able to communicate with each other directly without needing something else, isn't it? Don't know how, especially when we have moving robots.

Comment: Oh yeah.. In that case you would need bluetooth, ad hoc, mesh or wifi direct networking.   Will be an interesting setup with ROS I would guess, just never done it myself.